# Android App crashes everytime I do a HTTP POST

Tags: java, android, http-post

I am trying to create a simple android app that does a http POST. However, my app crashes everytime I hit send. I am able to send the same request using other REST API clients.

http://xx.xx.xx.xx:2000/newUser (content-Type: application/JSON)
{
"first": "test",
"last":"test",
"email": "test",
"pass": "test"
}

Here's the java file

```
public void send(View v)
{
    try {
        JSONObject parameters = new JSONObject();
        parameters.put("email", "test");
        parameters.put("pass", "test");
        parameters.put("first", "test");
        parameters.put("last", "test");

        String request        = "http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:2000/newUser";
        URL    url            = new URL( request );
        HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /*milliseconds*/);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/JSON");
        conn.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty( "Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        conn.setUseCaches( false );
        conn.connect();
        OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(parameters.toString());
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());

        // Close streams and disconnect.
        writer.close();
        out.close();
        conn.disconnect();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I do have the android.permission.INTERNET set in the manifests file. My app crashes at
     conn.connect();
     OutputStream out ...

Any ideas???

Comment: Where is your logcat ??? post it

Comment: please show your stack trace.

Comment: Try yo make network request on GUI thread. Use AsyncTask

Comment: you can see the error in the stacktrace. always.

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi Yes we need this.

Answer (score 0):

Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) .

you can not perform network operations on main thread.

Answer (score 0):

> ASYNCTASK

AsyncTask is an abstract class provided by Android which helps us to use the UI thread properly. This class allows us to perform long/background operations and show its result on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads
for more details go through this.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html